# Asynchronous JAX-WS multiple calls

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, executorservice, callable

We have an asmx web service. I have to test the client using WSDL. I have successfully implemented the code for Client Side Asynchronous Mappings. The problem is that I can't understand how can a client make multiple simultaneous requests to the server. I have seen the `Future` interface but I don't understand how can I have concurrent calls using it.

```
private void callAsyncCallback(String encodedString, String key) {

    DataManipulation service = new DataManipulation();

    try { // Call Web Service Operation(async. callback)
        DataManipulationSoap port = service.getDataManipulationSoap12();
        // TODO initialize WS operation arguments here
        AsyncHandler<GetDataResponse> asyncHandler =
                new AsyncHandler<GetDataResponse>() {

                    @Override
                    public void handleResponse(Response<GetDataResponse> response) {
                        try {
                            // TODO process asynchronous response here
                            System.out.println("Output at:::   " + new Date().toString());
                            System.out.println("************************Result = " + response.get().getGetDataResult());
                        } catch (Exception ex) {
                            // TODO handle exception
                        }
                    }
                };
        Future<? extends Object> result = port.getDataAsync(encodedString,key, asyncHandler);
        while (!result.isDone()) {
            // do something
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // TODO handle custom exceptions here
    }

}
```

I know I can do something in the `while(!result.isDone())` loop but how can I call the web service here again?

The purpose is that I have to send multiple files to the web service. The WS performs some operation on those files and sends some result back. I want the client to send all files simultaneously so that the time taken is very less. I have tried calling the method `callAsyncCallback` multiple times in my code but it goes to the next line only when the first call comes back to the client.

**Edit**

Can anyone give me some pointers to the ExecutorService? I have read about some options like invokeAll but I'm unable to relate it to JAX-WS. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I strongly advise that you always use [ListenableFuture](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ListenableFutureExplained) instead of Future in all of your code
it much more comfortable and it's not your own bike

Example:

```
   ListeningExecutorService service = MoreExecutors.listeningDecorator(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10));
    ListenableFuture<Explosion> explosion = service.submit(new Callable<Explosion>() {
      public Explosion call() {
        return pushBigRedButton();
      }
    });
    Futures.addCallback(explosion, new FutureCallback<Explosion>() {
      // we want this handler to run immediately after we push the big red button!
      public void onSuccess(Explosion explosion) {
        walkAwayFrom(explosion);
      }
      public void onFailure(Throwable thrown) {
        battleArchNemesis(); // escaped the explosion!
      }
    });
```